# Performance explanation: code runs faster with unused variable

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jvm

I was doing some performance testing earlier and can't explain the results I obtain.

When running the test below, if I uncomment `private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` the performance improves significantly. On my machine, the test runs in 70-90 ms when that field is present vs. 650 ms when it is commented out.

I have also noticed that if I change the print statement to `System.out.println((end - start) / 1000000);`, the test without the variable runs in 450-500 ms instead of 650 ms. It has no effect when the variable is present.

**My questions:**

1. Can anyone explain the factor of almost 10 with or without the variable, considering that I don't even use that variable?
2. How can that print statement change the performance (especially since it comes **after** the performance measurement window)?

ps: when run sequentially, the 3 scenarios (with variable, without variable, with different print statement) all take around 260ms.

```
public class SOTest {

    private static final int ITERATIONS = 10000000;
    private static final int THREADS = 4;

    private volatile long id = 0L;
    //private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);
        final List<SOTest> objects = new ArrayList<SOTest>();
        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
            objects.add(new SOTest());
        }

        //warm up
        for (SOTest t : objects) {
            getRunnable(t).run();
        }

        long start = System.nanoTime();

        for (SOTest t : objects) {
            executor.submit(getRunnable(t));
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(objects.get(0).id + " " + (end - start) / 1000000);
    }

    public static Runnable getRunnable(final SOTest object) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
                    object.id++;
                }
            }
        };
        return r;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

See below the results of 10 runs with the 3 scenarios:

- without the variable, using the short print statement
- without the variable, using the long print statement (prints one of the objects)
- sequential run (1 thread)
- with the variable

```
1   657 473 261 74
2   641 501 261 78
3   651 465 259 86
4   585 462 259 78
5   639 506 259 68
6   659 477 258 72
7   653 479 259 82
8   645 486 259 72
9   650 457 259 78
10  639 487 272 79
```

Comment: How often did you repeat your test? Are these times average values?

Comment: @Baz Yes these are averages on several runs (say 10-15 runs) and the results are fairly stable from one run to another.

Comment: Did you [statistically prove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) it is indeed different? Could be just noise that results from "randomness". If you didn't, I would first try to repeat the experiment and collect a big enough sample to make statistical claims about the data. It is not much of an effort and can prevent a lot of headaches (in other cases if not in here).

Comment: Are you testing over and over, didn't making pauses or cleaning process' remains? It just make all the difference!

Comment: Not certain that `main` in `SOTest` passed to Thread have no impact. Try to put your threaded parts in another class.

Comment: @waldyr.ar Each test is run with a clean JVM

Comment: to do so low level performance analysis you should look on bytecode, not on java code

Comment: @amit I have not done a proper statistical analysis but the results (see my edit) seem stable enough (low variance) in each case that the difference can't be explained by noise.

Comment: I've noticed that `private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` can be replaced with `{System.out.println("wtf");}` lol

Comment: @BorisTreukhov Haha - it does work too indeed ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Clear (false) sharing**

due to the layout in the memory the objects share cache lines...
It has been explained a lot of times (even on this site): here is a [good source](https://sites.google.com/site/1024cores/home/lock-free-algorithms/false-sharing---false) for further read. The issue is applicable to C# [just as much](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2009/10/20/FalseSharingIsNoFun.aspx) (or C/C++)

When you pad the object by adding the commented out line, the sharing is less and you see boost in the performance.

*Edit: I missed the 2nd question:*

---

> How can that print statement change the performance (especially since
> it comes after the performance measurement window)?

I guess not enough warming, print both the GC and compilation logs so you can be sure there is no interference and  the code is actually compiled.  `java -server` needs 10k iterations preferably not all in main loop to generate good code.

Comment: This should be easy to verify: replace the line with `private final Object list = null;` and see if it has the same effect.
`

Comment: @Tom, not so much - this will add **4 bytes only**, new ArrayList adds 10*4(or8) bytes for references, 4size, modcount 4, and 2 object headers.

Comment: Ah, true - i was thinking about the effect on alignment of instances of `SOTest`, but if course those are allocated interspersed with the list instances.

Comment: do like that. 8+8 volatile longs (`long l0, l2, l3....l7`); `volatile long id;` `volatile l8, l9, long la, lb, lc,... lf` (you have to pad both from front and end)

Comment: I disagree about the affects of  the print statement.  I don't think this is anything to do with warming.  I suspect it is optimization around use or no use of the `volatile`.  See my answer.

Comment: @Gray, yes, the extra string will offset the memory too - hence less cache lines may collide, I see I have not mentioned in the answer. Actually volatiles skip optimizations like, caching loads [which may lead to 'constant' folding] and the issue memory barriers if the hardware needs 'em. Java7 may skip unused non-volatile fields in the object memory layout (dunno if the optimization is still active)

Comment: @Gray, baring the above skipped optimizations and issued barriers volatiles are no different. I can't be sure if the write of `id++` would be deferred but the code is bound to be slow even if volatile from `id` is removed.

Comment: No, @bestss.  If you remove the `volatile`, the code runs in 3ms.  It's all about the volatile.

Comment: @Gray, yay the loop was optimized away and reduced to i+=ITERATIONS;

Comment: @bestsss The architects of LMAX Disruptor rely a lot on cache line padding and they did have to deal with an issue of even `volatile long` fields being optimized away. Here's a link to the `PaddedLong` class they created which includes a `sumPaddingToPreventOptimization()` method: https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/util/PaddedLong.java

Comment: @AndrewBissel, I know the code of disruptor quite well actually, yet they are very far from the 1st to do so (in java), for instance look at j.u.c.Exchanger$Slot, it has had padding for ages albeit only from one side. The new promised `@Contended`  annotation is going to solve the case once introduced, here is a JSR166 discussion on the topic: http://jsr166-concurrency.10961.n7.nabble.com/Contended-JEP-142-td5081.html Side note: only certain hotspot versions optimized away the non-volatile fields.

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting a subtle effect of the executing hardware. You SOTest objects are very small in memory, so all 4 instances may fit into the same cache line in memory. Since you are using a volatile this will cause cache trashing between different cores (only one core may have the cache line dirty).

When you comment in the ArrayList, the memory layout changes (the ArrayList is created in between to SOTest instances) and the volatile fields now go into different cache lines. Problem for the CPU disappears, thus performance skyrockets.

Proof: Comment out ArrayList and put instead in:

```
long waste1, waste2, waste3, waste4, waste5, waste6, waste7, waste8;
```

This enlarges your SOTest objects by 64 bytes (the size of one cache line on pentium processors). Performance is now the same as with ArrayList in.

Comment: @assyalias "put instead in", or in other words *replace ArrayList with* (damn typo, *not* should have read *now*, didn't see it at first, thanks)

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, and I have no idea how to verify it, but this might be related to caching. With the ArrayList present your objects become much larger, so a smaller number of them fits in some given cached memory area resulting in more cache misses.

On thing you actually could try is to use ArrayLists of different size, thus changing the memory footprint of your class instances and see if it has an effect on performance.

Comment: Changing the size of the arraylist does not seem to make a difference. However, the class only holds a reference to the arraylist, so I suppose changing its size does not change the class' size.

Comment: It's not about the `ArrayList` at all.  `new String("foo")` does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty interesting journey.  This is more a "here are my results answer".  I suspect/hope others will come up with better responses.

You are obviously hitting some interesting optimization points.  I suspect that the addition of the `objects.get(0).id` in the long `println` statement is removing some optimizations around the usage of the `id` field.  Aside from the `++` there are no other usage of `id` so maybe the optimizer is optimizing away some number of the accesses to `volatile id` which results in a speed improvement.  Just accessing the `id` field with a `long x = objects.get(0).id;` causes the same performance improvement.

The `List` field is much more interesting.  The same performance improvement happens if the field `private String foo = new String("weofjwe");` is added but *not* if it is `private String foo = "weofjwe";` which is not creating an object since the `"..."` is done at compilation time.  I was *sure* that `final` was relevant but it seems not to be.  I can only speculate that this has something to do with constructor optimizations with the addition of the `new` causing an optimization to be stopped although I would have though `volatile` would have done that more effectively.

Comment: Sure @bestsss but why does the addition of the (for example) `new String("...")` change it?

Comment: the string goes after the object and contains extra padding, incl. char[]